# The working copy <Project name> failed to commit files. - The repository has an uncompleted operation

Tags: xcode, git, bitbucket

I've just updated my Xcode from 6 to 7 (and code from Swift 1.2 to Swift 2.0) and try to create new branch in Xcode. After that I can't push my code to Bitbucket.

Is there a way how can I delete repository from directory and setup Bitbucket again and maybe push to another (a new one) repository? Fix of this problem will be great, but I will be satisfied even with move to another repository.

Comment: Find out what the dangling command is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with installation of GitHub. I had a master repository. After reinstall and resetup everything works like before.

EDIT: For anyone who has a problem with Xcode and GIT I have a best advice. Don't use it. Use for example [Source Tree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com)

When you start developing for a living, you are gonna have to use more reliable solution for GIT. Imagine you have 70 branches. Using Source Tree you can easily solve conflicts and other things about working in team. Xcode GIT solution is not reliable and you are gonna be only frustrated.

Answer (score 20):

I had this error in xcode 7.1 on a year old project that was working fine. In my case I have a project with the default local repository created by xcode. For anyone who is not going to re-install and re-setup. It is possible to find out what the dangling command is and fix it from command line.

To find the dangling command Open Terminal from the project directory:

**xcrun git status**

In my case the status returned:

**On branch master
You are currently rebasing.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")**

To fix the problem I used:

**xcrun git rebase --skip**

Comment: The one that worked for me is `xcrun git rebase --abort`

Answer (score 2):

In my case I ran `git status` which revealed that `You are currently bisecting`. (I was doing a `bisect` and must had forgotten to reset). I did a `git bisect reset` and attached the head to my latest commit and it was all fine afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

When I am merging from currentBranchA into branchB, I got conflicts,I didn't want to solve the conflicts immediately and quit the merging process. But when I try to merge again, the Xcode shows "The working copy  is currently in the middle of another operation..."

I opened the terminal ，`cd` to the project directory, and check the git status:

`git status`

it shows:

```
On branch currentBranchA
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/currentBranchA'.

All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
  (use "git commit" to conclude merge)
```

**Just do it as it says.** Continue to input

`git commit` and click `Ctrl + C` to close the commit message window.

The problem will be zero.